# Change color - hover effect

Tags: css

I am trying to change color at the hover effect to blue at the three gold buttons below the big picture on the start page. http://www.businesspodden.se

I successfully changed color when the mouse "hovers", but it's not correct. I have been trying a lot.

I don't know what to do, can someone help me out with this problem?

**I did:**

```
.qodef-hover-background {
  background-color: #2487c9 !important;
}
```

Comment: " but its not correctly." What is not correct?

Comment: @AbdullahAlemadi all the hover color will be blue, not red. you will see border and then it zoom in it is red

Comment: Please describe what's the effect you want to achieve. Otherwise we're unable to help you. Also please [create a MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of linking to an external website.

Comment: I see you fixed the problem by adding border with same color :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.qodef-hover-background:hover { 
    color: blue; 
}
```